# Linear regression on a dataframe -reshape error

Tags: arrays, dataframe, linear-regression, reshape, series

I would like to create a linear regression on my data.

I have tried to reshape my dataframe into an array. I have been through the following questions:

[pandas crashes on repeated DataFrame.reset_index()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12203901/pandas-crashes-on-repeated-dataframe-reset-index/12204428)

[sklearn error ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for dtype('float64')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31323499/sklearn-error-valueerror-input-contains-nan-infinity-or-a-value-too-large-for)

[AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53723928/attributeerror-series-object-has-no-attribute-reshape)

[Invalid character in identifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14844687/invalid-character-in-identifier)

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression


X = df_ind["ppentq"]
y = df_ind["xsgay"]
z = df_ind['revtq']

reg = LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
reg.score(X, y)
```

I get the error:
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[4.1835757  4.15731936 4.19720195 ... 7.46244352 7.51525252 7.58601316].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

I want to reshape, but when I do:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'reshape'

I'm a total novice/self-taught. I appreciate any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

Just use tensorflow. Also, use df.to_numpy() to transform into an array

Answer (score 0):

Actually the fit method requires your X-array to be 2D or higher. You can simply reshape the variable X using:

```py
    X_matrix = X.values.reshape(-1,1)
```

That's it!!!!!